# nginx and gunicorn 502 bad gateway

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to publish the project I created with Django using **gunicorn** and **nginx**. But when I visit my server's ip address it returns **502 Bad Gateway**. I've been dealing with this error for 4 days. Can you help me please ?

**/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/DjangoLearning
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/DjangoLearning-_DwN_DVL/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/DjangoLearning/myproject.sock --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings.production config.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 52.205.77.21;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/DjangoLearning/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

**/home/ubuntu/DjangoLearning/config/settings/production.py**

```
from .base import *
import sentry_sdk
from sentry_sdk.integrations.django import DjangoIntegration


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.osmanefekurt.com', "127.0.0.1", "52.205.77.21"]


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': config("DB_NAME"),
        'USER': config("DB_USER"),
        'PASSWORD': config("DB_PASSWORD"),
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}



sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn=config("dsn"),
    integrations=[
        DjangoIntegration(),
    ],
    traces_sample_rate=1.0,
    send_default_pii=True
)


AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config("ACCES_KEY_ID")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config("SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'osmanefes3'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age= 86400',
}
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'config.storage_backend.MediaStorage'
```

I deleted and reinstalled ubuntu twice. I uninstalled and reinstalled Nginx. I checked the configuration files. But I still couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Does nginx have permission to open that unix socket? Typically it runs as user www-data. Since you're not in the same group as that user, that would imply that every directory in that path needs to be world-executable and the socket itself needs to have world read/write permissions turned on. You can use `chown` to change directory/socket permissions.

Comment: sudo chown www-data:www-data myproject.sock - 
sudo chmod 660 myproject.sock

I gave permission using these commands but it still didn't work.

Comment: checked error logs? you may find reason of 502.